# Display output of fs.readdirSync() in front end HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am very new to `node.js` and have been googling for a solution to the problem stated in my question title above.

Basically I am building a simple web api that allows users to upload their files and then query them individually after that. So I am trying to figure out how to display the list of files in the server directory so instead of them remembering the exact file name, they can pick it from the list.

Here's my full html code `project/public/index.html` (**EDIT** - after answered by Oorja)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <style>
        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            min-width: 230px;
            overflow: auto;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .show {display:block;}
    </style>

    <body>
        <h1>api service</h1>
        <br>
        <div id="upload_form">
            <h3>Upload images</h3>
            <form action="/api/uploadImages" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                <input type="file" name="image" multiple="multiple"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload">
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="query_images">
            <h3>Query images</h3>
            <form action="/api/queryImages" method="get" enctype="text/plain">
                <input type="text" name="image_name"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Query">
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="show_list()" class="dropbtn">Images</button>
            <div id="image_list" class="dropdown-content">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search for your images..." id="userInput">
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            function show_list() {
                var image_list = document.getElementById("image_list");
                $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/list-files', function(data) {
                    data.forEach(function(file) {
                        $(image_list).append($('<a href="http://localhost:8080/uploaded_files/' + file + '">' + file + '</a>'));
                    })
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And below is the javascript full code `project/server.js` (**EDIT** - after answered by Oorja)

```
var express = require('express'),
    multer = require('multer'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    path = require('path')
    fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

var imageStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './uploaded_files');
    },

    filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '_' + Date.now() + '_' + file.originalname);
    }
});

var upload = multer({
    storage: imageStorage,
    fileFilter: function(req, file, callback) {
        console.log('Checking file extension...');
        var extension = path.extname(file.originalname);
        if (extension == '.jpg' || extension == '.png' || extension == '.jpeg') {
            console.log('Extension looks good!');
            callback(null, true);
        } else {
            callback('Please upload images only!', false);
        }
    }
}).array('image');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/uploaded_files', express.static('./upload_files'));

// define http methods handlers
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
});

app.get('/list-files', function(req, res) {
    var files = fs.readdirSync('./uploaded_files');
    res.json(files);
})

app.get('/api/queryImages', function(req, res) {
    var imageName = req.query.image_name
    console.log(imageName);
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'uploaded_files', imageName));
});

app.post('/api/uploadImages', function(req, res) {
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.end('Something went wrong!');
        }
        console.log('Upload successful!')
        res.send('Successfully uploaded images!');
    });
});

app.listen(port=8080, function(a) {
    console.log('Listening to port ' + port);
});
```

The javascript works `/list-files` as I can see the list of files in my console or if I go to `/list-files` url, however, I cannot figure out how to send the output to front end - I don't know how to connect them - so then when I click on the `button` under `div class="dropdown"` they will appear as a list `<a>` element.

Could someone please point me in the right direction or even better, give me an example?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**
Output of `files` from the javascript above `/list-files` is as below

```
[ '.DS_Store',
  'Screen Shot 2018-06-02 at 2.15.10 pm.png',
  'aaa.png',
  'bbb.png',
  'ccc.png',
  'ddd.png',
  'eee.png' ]
```

Also, to clarify, I am using `Express` framework to build this web api.

Comment: how does `files` looks like

Comment: @brk just made an edit to the question. I am just trying to list the file names. - or if there's an easy way to display them as thumbnails, that'd be awesome too!

Comment: What you need is server-side Templating Engines, e.g., Handlebars. You can google them. https://www.google.com.au/amp/s/colorlib.com/wp/top-templating-engines-for-javascript/amp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the list of files ready, make an API end-point for it. Say, `/get-files`. Assuming you're using `express` as a node.js server, you can do this -

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();
// Makes your upload_files directory public. Don't use this in a real app. 
// Create a separate route to serve file data. This is just for brevity of code.
app.use('/upload_files', express.static('./upload_files'))

app.get('/get-files', (req, res) => {
    // your logic of getting file names
    const files = fs.readdirSync('./upload_files');
    res.json(files);
});

app.listen(3000); // start a server at localhost:3000
```

Now, on your frontend, you can open an XHR GET request to fetch the name of files you have on the node.js server like so -

```
function show_list() {
    var image_list= document.getElementById('image_list');
    // Assuming you have jQuery as well...
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/get-files', function (data) {
        data.forEach(file => {
            // Do something with the file name 
            $(image_list).append($('<a href="http://localhost:3000/upload_files/' + file + '">' + file  + '</a>'));
        })
    });
}
```

You can read more about Express [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).
You can also do what Tamas has done with Server-side templating. It will send the data along with the `HTML` file but I doubt if that is what you asked for.

Comment: this works when i visit `http://localhost:3000/get-files` however, when i just click on the button, it does not load anything. what am i missing?

Comment: I have edited my questions with full `index.html` and `server.js` code. @Oorja

Comment: I think the problem is in styles section with `display: none`. Also, check out the line -> `app.use('/uploaded_files', express.static('./upload_files'));`. If the directory name has been changed to `uploaded_files` update it here as well.

Comment: Also, you can use `express-generator` by installing it globally with npm. It gives you boilerplate starter app with basic file structure and a templating engine!

Comment: Lastly, the jQuery file should also be a public static asset. So, you have to add `app.use('/jquery', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist/'));` in server.js. Then in `HTML`, just use it like `<script src="/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

You should try a template engine like [EJS](http://ejs.co/).

**Example usage if you use [express](https://expressjs.com/):**

EJS uses the `views` folder in root for html files default, so create it and put your `index.html` there.

**0.** Install EJS: `npm install ejs`

**1.** Include EJS in express: `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`

**2.** Add to your route: `res.render('index', {files: files});`

**3.** Get it in HTML, modify your index.html (put it where you need):

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { %>
     <a href="<%= files[i] %>"><%= files[i] %></a>
<% }; %>
```

**Or** if you need it as a JS variable use:

```
<script> var files = <%- JSON.stringify(files) %>; </script>
```

[More information](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application)

Comment: so do you mean my html `index.html` file where this line  `<a href="something">something</a>` is (as per my question above) will be replaced by your step 3?

Comment: Yes, if you need there, I guessed you need.